# C++ headers inclusions

Tags: c++, header, include

I am working on a project, each header file has a preprocessor include guard.
My includes are made like this:

(file -> includes)

main.cpp -> header.h; Character.h

header.h -> vector, iostream, ... , DataFiles.h

Character.h -> DataFiles.h, header.h, CharFrame.h

CharFrame.h -> DataFiles.h, header.h

Everything work fine. But if I just erase the main.cpp's #include "Character.h" to move it in header.h, I get lots of errors at compilation. So now it is:

main.cpp -> header.h

header.h -> ... , DataFiles.h, Character.h.

What's the difference?

Here is my compilator output:

```
Inspiron-1545:~/Desktop/LF2_linux$ g++ -Wall main.cpp DataFiles.cpp header.cpp Character.cpp CharFrame.cpp -lSDL -lSDL_image -lSDL_ttf -o test
In file included from header.h:13:0,
             from CharFrame.h:12,
             from CharFrame.cpp:1:
Character.h:55:15: error: ‘CharFrame’ was not declared in this scope
Character.h:55:25: error: template argument 1 is invalid
Character.h:55:25: error: template argument 2 is invalid
```

If the include is put back into the main.cpp, then it compiles without any error.

If you feel my code IS necessary I will edit this post and paste everything.

Here are the lines of interest:

```
header.h:13 ->
 #include "Character.h"
CharFrame.h:12 -> 
 #include "header.h"
CharFrame.cpp:1 -> 
 #include "CharFrame.h"
Character.h:55 ->  
 std::vector <CharFrame*> *frame;
```

Comment: Sounds like `header.h` uses `CharFrame`, but it is included (used) in `CharFrame.h` prior to `CharFrame` declaration. So compiler stumbles upon `CharFrame` before it has been declared.

Comment: If you are doing what you are saying, there should be no difference. But for some reason, compiler is unable to identify the type `CharFrame`. Can you post a [SSCE](http://sscce.org/) to reproduce the issue ?

Comment: Does DataFiles.h include any of the others?

Comment: I don't think you can have 2 headers (header.h, charframe.h) that include each other directly. If you have [circular dependency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency), you can use one of many solutions.

Comment: @Violet Giraffe: I think you found the problem, eahc file including the other... Is there a way to bypass that, or do I have to rethink my code structure from scratch?

Comment: @Mahesh there is obviously a difference :)

Comment: @AlexandreToqué [this](http://prasanthj86.blogspot.com/2012/09/resolving-circular-dependency-in-c.html) suggests a forward declaration as a solution. forward-declare charframe class in header.h and implement it in header.cpp

Comment: @AlexandreToqué Good you found it yourself :)

Comment: @khajvah Thanks Im trying this method. but it's a mess for now.

Comment: It appears the forward declaration should not keep the #include s, else the compiler complains about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your change created an inclusion cycle between Character.h and header.h.

Presumably, Character.h relies on some declarations in headers.h. Now, with your change, the following happens:

1. headers.h is included, defines its include guard, and the preprocessor starts examining its contents.
2. headers.h includes Character.h, before it makes its own declarations.

   1. Character.h defines its include guard, the preprocessor reads its contents.
   2. Character.h includes header.h to get the definitions it needs.

      1. headers.h, however sees its include guard, and is parsed as empty. No definitions are made yet.
   3. Character.h definitions are read.
3. headers.h definitions are read.

As you can see, the definitions in Character.h are read before the definitions in header.h, which they rely upon.

The best way to fix a circular inclusion is to replace `#include`s with forward declarations whenever possible. In some rare cases it might become necessary to actually mix declarations with includes, but you should avoid such a thing at all costs.

Comment: Thanks this completes the explanations in khajvah's link , in which the exemple keeps the #include s where it should not as you just said :)